# Undo Button Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, undo

I have a drawing app that uses CALayer sublayers for the actual drawing of an image.  I currently have an IBAction that contains code to remove the sublayers from the superlayer.  However everytime I run it, I get a BAD ACCESS error that crashes my app.  I'm wondering why it won't allow me to remove the sublayers.  Also, in theory, this approach would remove all of the layers entirely.  I would ideally want it to only undo the last layers that were drawn.  Any suggestions on what I should do?  Thanks.

```
var locale: CALayer {
    return layerView.layer
}

@IBAction func undoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers
    for layer in sublayers {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }   
}

func setUpLayer() -> CALayer {
    locale.contents = image
    locale.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter

    return locale
}

func subLayerDisplay() {
    var newLayer = CALayer()
    var tempRect = CGRectMake(prevLocation.x, prevLocation.y, 50, 50)
    newLayer.frame = tempRect
    newLayer.contents = image

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(newLayer, below: locale)
}
```

Comment: try view.layer.sublayers.last.removeFromSuperlayer()

Comment: Does it only crash when there are no sublayers? I've encountered `layer.sublayers` being nil before so iterating on it would cause a crash.

Comment: Actually it looks like you're removing all the layers from all the views in your view controller. That's likely to cause a crash. You should be adding your layers in a sublayer or subview or at least tracking added layers in their own array.

Comment: leonardo, the view.layer.sublayers.last.removeFromSuperlayer() code doesn't seem to be working for this problem.  brian, if i were to add them into their own array i come to the problem of removing them because they are already a part of an unmutable NSArray after the touchesMoved function calls func subLayerDisplay()

Comment: Adding it to a subview worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To sum up, you can add your layer to a view, and then deal with the view, which will make life much more easier.

When you add the button, you can do

```
view.tag = 1
self.addSubView(view)
```

When you want to remove it

```
let view = self.viewWithTag(1) as! UIView
view.removeFromSuperView()
```